# What's wrong with this reflection code? GetFields() is returning an empty array

Tags: c#, reflection, type-parameter

C#, Net 2.0

Here's the code (I took out all my domain-specific stuff, and it still returns an empty array):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChildClass cc = new ChildClass();
            cc.OtherProperty = 1;

            FieldInfo[] fi = cc.GetType().GetFields();
            Console.WriteLine(fi.Length);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class BaseClass<T>
    {
        private int myVar;

        public int MyProperty
        {
            get { return myVar; }
            set { myVar = value; }
        }


    }

    class ChildClass : BaseClass<ChildClass>
    {
        private int myVar;

        public int OtherProperty
        {
            get { return myVar; }
            set { myVar = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The parameterless `GetFields()` returns *public* fields. If you want non-public ones, use:

```
cc.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

or whatever appropriate combination you want - but you *do* need to specify at least one of `Instance` and `Static`, otherwise it won't find either. You can specify both, and indeed public fields as well, to get everything:

```
cc.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | 
                       BindingFlags.Static |
                       BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                       BindingFlags.Public);
```

Comment: +1 This is the one, you *must* specify Instance as well as NonPublic.

Comment: Cheers for the answer! I'm having trouble understanding it though. Could someone please explain why Instance or Static is required along with NonPublic for private fields?

Comment: @rory.ap: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 12):

Since the field is private, you need to use the overload of GetFields() that allows you to specify [BindingFlags.NonPublic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx).

To make this work, change it to:

```
FieldInfo[] fi = cc.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify that you want the private (NonPublic) fields

Change to:

```
FieldInfo[] fi = cc.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: This will return 0 elements, as well.  You need to include BindingFlags.Instance in addition to BindingFlags.NonPublic.