# Compare two objects and find the differences

Tags: c#, asp.net

what is the best way to compare two objects and find the differences?

```
Customer a = new Customer();
Customer b = new Customer();
```

Answer (score 252, accepted):

One Flexible solution: You could use reflection to enumerate through all of the properties and determine which are and are not equal, then return some list of properties and both differing values.

Here's an example of some code that is a good start for what you are asking. It only looks at Field values right now, but you could add any number of other components for it to check through reflection. It's implemented using an extension method so all of your objects could use it.

TO USE

```
    SomeCustomClass a = new SomeCustomClass();
    SomeCustomClass b = new SomeCustomClass();
    a.x = 100;
    List<Variance> rt = a.DetailedCompare(b);
```

My sample class to compare against

```
    class SomeCustomClass
    {
        public int x = 12;
        public int y = 13;
    }
```

AND THE MEAT AND POTATOES

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

static class extentions
{
    public static List<Variance> DetailedCompare<T>(this T val1, T val2)
    {
        List<Variance> variances = new List<Variance>();
        FieldInfo[] fi = val1.GetType().GetFields();
        foreach (FieldInfo f in fi)
        {
            Variance v = new Variance();
            v.Prop = f.Name;
            v.valA = f.GetValue(val1);
            v.valB = f.GetValue(val2);
            if (!Equals(v.valA, v.valB))
                variances.Add(v);

        }
        return variances;
    }


}
class Variance
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
    public object valA { get; set; }
    public object valB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use if (!Equals(v.valA, v.valB)) in place of if (!v.valA.Equals(v.valB)) to prevents NullException

Comment: Why not auto properties ?

Comment: If .GetFields() does not return everything you want (like private fields), check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040803/whats-wrong-with-this-reflection-code-getfields-is-returning-an-empty-array

Comment: 5 years later and this was totally what I was looking for.  I just had to switch to GetProperties and it worked like a charm (for my needs)

Comment: I like this idea, but the code here doesn't work. Here's a fiddle that shows a couple of fixes: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FhzcrS

Comment: Was answered 8 years ago, but still relevant.
Btw, if the property of type `Dictionary` how to compare it properly in a most efficient way?

Comment: To skip navigation properties in object added conditions to skip iteration when  `property.PropertyType is IEnumerable` or `property.PropertyType.IsClass && property.PropertyType != typeof(string)`

Comment: outputs a bund of .net language names when the class is a child class, can this be modified to compare child classes too?

Comment: Not to be pendantic, but it _will_ show up in Visual studio code - why are properties `valA` and `valB` not capitalized? I suppose with conventional naming practice they should be.

Answer (score 14):

The [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) method and the [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) interface could be used to know if two objects are equal but they won't allow you to know the differences between the objects. You could use reflection by comparing each property values.

Yet another approach might consist into serializing those instances into some text format and compare the differences inside the resulting strings (XML, JSON, ...).

Comment: I think he's not looking for equality tests, but rather the collection of reasons why the two objects do not match.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't really make sense seeing as we have no idea what's contained in the Customer class

Comment: @deepee1, @Rob, I agree that `Equals` and `IEquatable<T>` doesn't allow for finding the differences. Reflection could be used in this case.