# How to find difference between lists?

Tags: c#, list, linq, generics

So I am trying to find the difference between 2 lists of type Person. This is the person class:

```
class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(int age, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.Age = age;
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

and in my code, I create 2 variables, `List<Person> list1` and `List<Person> list2`.

I fill list1 with the following variables:

```
list1.Add(new Person(20, "first1", "last1"));
list1.Add(new Person(30, "first2", "last2"));
list1.Add(new Person(40, "first3", "last3"));
list1.Add(new Person(50, "first4", "last4"));
```

and fill list2 with the following:

```
list2.Add(new Person(30, "first2", "last2"));
list2.Add(new Person(50, "first4", "last4"));
```

My goal is to have another list (`List<Person> list3`) with `list1[0]` and `list[2]` since that is what is not included in `list2`. I tried using `list3 = list1.Except(list2).ToList();` but that just returns a copy of `list1` and if i do `list3 = list2.Except(list1).ToList();` it returns a copy of `list2`. How do I solve this? Am I using `Except()` right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636438/difference-between-two-lists) The exact duplicate, as well as [Get the differences between 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810438/get-the-differences-between-2-lists) They can be found after 1-2 minutes of googling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying issue here is that you need to ask yourself, what makes these objects equal? Just because you have assigned them equal property values, does NOT make them equal. For example, although `list1[1]` and `list2[0]`, seem identical, they are completely different instances of the Person object. Therefore, you need a way to tell when one Person object is "equal" to another.[Generate Equals and GetHashCode method overrides in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods?view=vs-2019).

This may help as well also, [Overriding Equals in C#](https://www.loganfranken.com/blog/692/overriding-equals-in-c-part-2/)

Hope this helps, please mark this as the answer if this does. Good luck!
Here is the code which works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list1 = new List<Person>();
        list1.Add(new Person(20, "first1", "last1"));
        list1.Add(new Person(30, "first2", "last2"));
        list1.Add(new Person(40, "first3", "last3"));
        list1.Add(new Person(50, "first4", "last4"));

        var list2 = new List<Person>();
        list2.Add(new Person(30, "first2", "last2"));
        list2.Add(new Person(50, "first4", "last4"));

        var list3 = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
    }
}

class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(int age, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.Age = age;
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Person);
    }

    public bool Equals(Person otherPerson)
    {
        return otherPerson != null && this.Age == otherPerson.Age && this.FirstName == otherPerson.FirstName && this.LastName == otherPerson.LastName;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Age.GetHashCode() + this.FirstName.GetHashCode() + this.LastName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Precisely. You can get a better hash function with less code by using tuples `GetHashCode => (Age, FirstName, LastName).GetHashCode();`. You might also do the same for equals.

Comment: Thank you so much, I spend a long time trying to figure out why it was acting all weird.

Comment: `Equals` override should take into account reference equality and use `ReferenceEquals` method

Comment: I love this answer, but one thing should be made clear here. Objects that override `GetHashCode` should be immutable. If their hash code changes during their lifetime it breaks any dictionary that uses them as a key.

Comment: Or limit the calculation of GetHashCode to immutable properties only. In this case there aren't any but that's easily remedied. However the custom EqualityComparer is probably better suited over IEquatable since the former won't be used by dictionaries implicitly

Answer (score 1):

The equality check used by `Except` will be ReferenceEquals (are they literally the same object instance) because this is the default way of comparing objects for equality unless specified otherwise.
If you want Except to compare your Person class by the Age, FirstName, and LastName properties then you need to override the Equals and GetHashCode methods on the Person class.

Once you've done this `list1.Except(list2).ToList()` should work

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netcore-3.1) class that overrides `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`:

```
public class PersonEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (x is null || y is null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return x.Age == y.Age && 
               x.FirstName == y.FirstName && 
               x.LastName == y.LastName;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return HashCode.Combine(obj.Age, obj.FirstName, obj.LastName);
    }
}
```

Then pass this comparer to [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Except__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) to get the difference:

```
var list3 = list1.Except(list2, new PersonEqualityComparer());
```

Full demo on [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gonJuH)