# Diferrence between two lists with nested values

Tags: c#, generics, nested-lists

I have to variables of a particular type, the classes for them are :

```
public class User
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<AccessibleSite> Sites { get; set; }
}


public class AccessibleSite
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}


public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string UserFriendlyName { get; set; }
}
```

A user can have many `AccessibleSite` under him and each site has a List of `Role` associated to it.

There are two objects of the `User` type. I need to find the difference between the two lists.

So far the code I have written is comparing only non List objects correctly.

```
static class extentions
{
    public static List<Variance> DetailedCompare<T>(this T val1, T val2)
    {
        List<Variance> variances = new List<Variance>();
        List<FieldInfo> fi = val1.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().ToList<FieldInfo>();
    foreach (FieldInfo f in fi)
    {
        Variance v = new Variance();
        v.Prop = f.Name;
        v.valA = f.GetValue(val1);
        v.valB = f.GetValue(val2);
        if (v.valA is System.Collections.IList && v.valA.GetType().IsGenericType)
        {
            foreach (var listItem in v.valA.DetailedCompare(v.valB))
            {
                variances.Add(listItem);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if ((v.valA != null && v.valB != null) && !v.valA.Equals(v.valB))
                variances.Add(v);
        }

    }
    return variances;
}



 class Variance
 {
     public string Prop { get; set; }
     public object valA { get; set; }
     public object valB { get; set; }

     public string ChangedFromText
     {
     get
     {
         return "value of " + Prop + " has changed from " + valA + " to " + valB;
     }
 }
```

The items in the list needs to be compared on the basis of ID.if stuff has changed or not.

I looked at the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951233/compare-two-objects-and-find-the-differences) but It would need me to create two diferrent classes , each for AccessibleSite and Roles. 
Is there any way we can write this using only one solution. Recursively maybe ? 
TIA

Comment: Is the order of the items in the lists significant? Makes a big difference to the solution!

Comment: I didnt get the question.Say,  I find AccessibleSite Id = 1 in the first object .
In the second object Of user I find the accessible site with the same ID and then compare the other values of AccessibleSite.
Same with the roles object

Answer (score 1):

The solution for something like this is very involved.

Here is an untested solution I whipped up.  I'll leave it to you to test and adjust it:

This class attribute is used to specify which field or property on a class should be treated as the Id value of instances of the class.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class IdPropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string IdProperty { get; private set; }
    public IdPropertyAttribute(string idProperty) { this.IdProperty = idProperty; }
}
```

The TExtensions class contains two extension methods and a number of supporting methods used for reflecting and analyzing the values between two object graphs.

```
public static class TExtensions
{

    public static Variance DetailedCompare<T>(this T val1, T val2)
    {
        return  val1.DetailedCompare(val2, null);
    }

    public static Variance DetailedCompare<T>(this T val1, T val2, string fieldName)
    {
        return  typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
                ?   TExtensions.enumerableCompare(val1, val2, fieldName)
                :   typeof(T).IsPrimitive
                    ?   TExtensions.valueCompare(val1, val2, fieldName)
                    :   TExtensions.objectCompare(val1, val2, fieldName);
    }

    private static Variance valueCompare<T>(T val1, T val2, string fieldName)
    {
        return  val1 != null && val2 != null && !val1.Equals(val2)
                ?   new Variance.ValueVariance<T>() { Prop = fieldName??"<root>", valA = val1, valB = val2 }
                :   null;
    }

    private static Variance objectCompare<T>(T val1, T val2, string fieldName)
    {
        var variance = new Variance.EnumerableVariance() {Prop = fieldName};

        List<FieldInfo> fi = val1.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().ToList<FieldInfo>();
        foreach (FieldInfo f in fi)
        {
            var subVariance = f.GetValue(val1).DetailedCompare(f.GetValue(val2), f.Name);

            if (subVariance != null)    variance.variances.Add(subVariance);
        }
        return variance;
    }

    private static Variance enumerableCompare<T>(T val1, T val2, string fieldName)
    {
        return  typeof(IEnumerable<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
                ?   TExtensions.homogeneousEnumerableCompare<T>(val1, val2, fieldName)
                :   TExtensions.heterogeneousEnumerableCompare<T>(val1, val2, fieldName);
    }

    private static Variance heterogeneousEnumerableCompare<T>(T val1, T val2, string fieldName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static Variance homogeneousEnumerableCompare<T>(T val1, T val2, string fieldName)
    {
        var subType     = typeof(T).GetGenericArguments()[0];
        return  typeof(KeyValuePair<,>).IsAssignableFrom(subType)
                ?   TExtensions.homogeneousKeyValueEnumerableCompare(subType, val1, val2, fieldName)
                :   subType.IsPrimitive
                    ?   homogeneousValueEnumerableCompare(subType, val1, val2, fieldName)
                    :   homogeneousObjectEnumerableCompare(subType, val1, val2, fieldName);
    }

    private static Variance homogeneousObjectEnumerableCompare<T>(Type subType, T val1, T val2, string fieldName)
    {
        var subMethod   =   typeof(TExtensions)
                            .GetMethod("typedHomogeneousObjectEnumerableCompare", BindingFlags.Static, null, new []{typeof(T), typeof(T), typeof(String)}, null)
                            .MakeGenericMethod(new []{typeof(T), subType});

        return (Variance) subMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {val1, val2, fieldName});
    }

    private static Variance typedHomogeneousObjectEnumerableCompare<T, TSubType>(T val1, T val2, string fieldName)
    {
        var idAttribute = typeof(TSubType).GetCustomAttribute<IdPropertyAttribute>(true);
        return  idAttribute == null
                ?   TExtensions.keyLessTypedHomogeneousObjectEnumerableCompare<T, TSubType>(val1, val2, fieldName)
                :   TExtensions.keyedTypedHomogeneousObjectEnumerableCompare<T, TSubType>(idAttribute, val1, val2, fieldName);
    }

    private static Variance keyLessTypedHomogeneousObjectEnumerableCompare<T, TSubType>(T val1, T val2, string fieldName)
    {
        var list1 = (IEnumerable<TSubType>) val1;
        var list2 = (IEnumerable<TSubType>) val2;
        return  list1.Count() != list2.Count()
                ?   new Variance.KeylessObjectEnumerableVariance() { Prop = fieldName, listACount = list1.Count(), listBCount = list2.Count() }
                :   null;
    }

    private static Variance keyedTypedHomogeneousObjectEnumerableCompare<T, TSubType>(IdPropertyAttribute idAttribute, T val1, T val2, string fieldName)
    {
        var idMember    = typeof(TSubType).GetMember(idAttribute.IdProperty).FirstOrDefault();
        if (idMember == null) throw new IdMemberNotFoundException(idAttribute.IdProperty, typeof(TSubType).FullName);

        var subMethod   =   typeof(TExtensions)
                            .GetMethod("subTypedKeyedTypedHomogeneousObjectEnumerableCompare", BindingFlags.Static, null, new []{typeof(T), typeof(T), typeof(String)}, null)
                            .MakeGenericMethod(new []{typeof(T), typeof(TSubType), (idMember is PropertyInfo ? ((PropertyInfo) idMember).PropertyType : ((FieldInfo) idMember).FieldType)});

        return (Variance) subMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {val1, val2, fieldName, idMember});
    }

    private static Variance subTypedKeyedTypedHomogeneousObjectEnumerableCompare<T, TSubType, TSubTypeKey>(T val1, T val2, string fieldName, MemberInfo idMember)
    {
        return  subTypedKeyedTypedHomogeneousObjectEnumerableCompareWithKeyFunc<T, TSubType, TSubTypeKey>
                (
                    val1,
                    val2,
                    fieldName,
                    idMember is PropertyInfo
                    ?   new Func<TSubType, TSubTypeKey>(item=>(TSubTypeKey) ((PropertyInfo) idMember).GetValue(item))
                    :   item=>(TSubTypeKey) ((FieldInfo) idMember).GetValue(item)
                );
    }

    private static Variance subTypedKeyedTypedHomogeneousObjectEnumerableCompareWithKeyFunc<T, TSubType, TSubTypeKey>(T val1, T val2, string fieldName, Func<TSubType, TSubTypeKey> getKey)
    {
        var set1        = ((IEnumerable<TSubType>) val1).ToDictionary(a=>getKey(a));
        var set2        = ((IEnumerable<TSubType>) val2).ToDictionary(a=>getKey(a));

        return TExtensions.DictionaryCompare<TSubTypeKey, TSubType>(set1, set2, fieldName);
    }

    private static Variance homogeneousValueEnumerableCompare<T>(Type subType, T val1, T val2, string fieldName)
    {
        var subMethod   =   typeof(TExtensions)
                            .GetMethod("typedHomogeneousValueEnumerableCompare", BindingFlags.Static, null, new []{typeof(T), typeof(T), typeof(String)}, null)
                            .MakeGenericMethod(new []{typeof(T), subType});

        return (Variance) subMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {val1, val2, fieldName});
    }

    private static Variance typedHomogeneousValueEnumerableCompare<T, TSubType>(T val1, T val2, string fieldName)
    {
        var variance    = new Variance.EnumerableVariance();
        var list1       = ((IEnumerable<TSubType>) val1).ToList();
        var list2       = ((IEnumerable<TSubType>) val1).ToList();

        foreach(var item in list1)  if (!list2.Contains(item))  variance.variances.Add(new Variance.ValueRemovedVariance<TSubType>() {Prop = fieldName, value = item});
        foreach(var item in list2)  if (!list1.Contains(item))  variance.variances.Add(new Variance.ValueAddedVariance<TSubType>() {Prop = fieldName, value = item});

        return variance;
    }

    private static Variance homogeneousKeyValueEnumerableCompare<T>(Type subType, T val1, T val2, string fieldName)
    {
        var keyType     = subType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var valueType   = subType.GetGenericArguments()[1];
        var subMethod   =   typeof(TExtensions)
                            .GetMethod("typedHomogeneousKeyValueEnumerableCompare", BindingFlags.Static, null, new []{typeof(T), typeof(T), typeof(String)}, null)
                            .MakeGenericMethod(new []{typeof(T), keyType, valueType});

        return (Variance) subMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {val1, val2, fieldName});
    }

    private static Variance typedHomogeneousKeyValueEnumerableCompare<T, TSubTypeKey, TSubTypeValue>(T val1, T val2, string fieldName)
    {
        var set1        = ((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TSubTypeKey, TSubTypeValue>>) val1).ToDictionary(a=>a.Key, a=>a.Value);
        var set2        = ((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TSubTypeKey, TSubTypeValue>>) val2).ToDictionary(a=>a.Key, a=>a.Value);

        return TExtensions.DictionaryCompare<TSubTypeKey, TSubTypeValue>(set1, set2, fieldName);
    }

    private static Variance DictionaryCompare<TSubTypeKey, TSubTypeValue>(Dictionary<TSubTypeKey, TSubTypeValue> set1, Dictionary<TSubTypeKey, TSubTypeValue> set2, string fieldName)
    {
        var variance    = new Variance.EnumerableVariance();

        foreach(var key in set1.Keys)
        {
            var subVariance =   !set2.ContainsKey(key) 
                                ?   new Variance.KeyedObjectRemovedVariance<TSubTypeKey>() {Prop = fieldName, key = key}
                                :   set1[key].DetailedCompare(set2[key], fieldName + "[" + key.ToString() + "]");

            if (subVariance != null) variance.variances.Add(subVariance);
        }

        foreach(var key in set2.Keys)  if (!set1.ContainsKey(key))  variance.variances.Add(new Variance.KeyedObjectRemovedVariance<TSubTypeKey>() {Prop = fieldName, key = key});

        return variance;
    }

}
```

This exception is needed to indicate that a class has been decorated with an IdAttribute, but the field or property specified was not found in the class during analysis.

```
public class IdMemberNotFoundException : ApplicationException
{
    public IdMemberNotFoundException(string memberName, string typeName) : base(memberName + " was not found in type " + typeName +  ".") {}
}
```

The variance class has been broken out into a base class with several sub classes to represent the various types of variances that can occur.

```
public abstract class Variance
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }

    public string GetChangedFromText() { return this.GetChangedFromText(null); }
    protected abstract string GetChangedFromText(string parent);

    public class ValueVariance<T> : Variance
    {
        public object valA { get; set; }
        public object valB { get; set; }

        protected override string GetChangedFromText(string parent)
        {
            return "value of " + (parent??"<root>") + "." + this.Prop + " has changed from " + this.valA + " to " + this.valB;
        }
    }

    public class EnumerableVariance : Variance
    {
        public List<Variance> variances   = new List<Variance>();

        protected override string GetChangedFromText(string parent)
        {
            StringBuilder   returnString    = new StringBuilder();
            foreach(var variance in this.variances)
            {
                returnString.Append(variance.GetChangedFromText(this.Prop));
            }

            return returnString.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class KeylessObjectEnumerableVariance : Variance
    {
        public int listACount;
        public int listBCount;
        protected override string GetChangedFromText(string parent)
        {
            return "count of keyless items " + (parent??"<root>") + "." + this.Prop + " has changed from " + this.listACount.ToString() + " to " + this.listBCount.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class ValueRemovedVariance<T> : Variance
    {
        public T value;
        protected override string GetChangedFromText(string parent)
        {
            return "value " + this.value.ToString() + " of " + (parent??"<root>") + "." + this.Prop + " was removed.";
        }
    }

    public class ValueAddedVariance<T> : Variance
    {
        public T value;
        protected override string GetChangedFromText(string parent)
        {
            return "value " + this.value.ToString() + " of " + (parent??"<root>") + "." + this.Prop + " was added.";
        }
    }

    public class KeyedObjectRemovedVariance<T> : Variance
    {
        public T key;
        protected override string GetChangedFromText(string parent)
        {
            return "key " + this.key.ToString() + " of " + (parent??"<root>") + "." + this.Prop + " was removed.";
        }
    }

    public class KeyedObjectAddedVariance<T> : Variance
    {
        public T key;
        protected override string GetChangedFromText(string parent)
        {
            return "key " + this.key.ToString() + " of " + (parent??"<root>") + "." + this.Prop + " was added.";
        }
    }

}
```

Your variances can include:

- Two primitive values differ.
- Value items in one heterogeneous list are missing from the second list.
- Value items are missing in one heterogeneous that are present in a second list.
- Keyed object items in one heterogeneous list are missing from the second list.
- Keyed object items are missing in one heterogeneous that are present in a second list.
- Object items that have been matched between two heterogeneous lists have variances.
- Value items in one homogeneous list are missing from the second list.
- Value items are missing in one homogeneous that are present in a second list.
- Keyed object items in one homogeneous list are missing from the second list.
- Keyed object items are missing in one homogeneous that are present in a second list.
- Object items that have been matched between two homogeneous lists have variances.
- Two object items have variances

The code above should hopefully address those variances.  You may find other cases.  Hopefully this gives you a good starting point.