# Get the difference between two lists of the same type of object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have two lists of the exact same type of object. One has more items than the other. I would like to find the difference between the two and have attempted multiple ways but all seem to return the full list and not the difference being one item or more.

```
        List<Permission> defaultPermList = defaultRole.Permissions.ToList();
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            List<Permission> rolePermList = role.Permissions.ToList();
            //All 3 below return the full set of defaultPermList. not the difference of the two lists
            var permissions1 = defaultPermList.RemoveAll(x => rolePermList.Contains(x));
            var permissions2 = defaultPermList.Where(x => !rolePermList.Contains(x)).ToList();
            var permissions3 = defaultPermList.Except(rolePermList).ToList();
        }
```

I have looked at numerous other questions and answers hence all my different attempts.

Comment: They're probably different objects which represent the same thing. Check your `Equals` method (or make one). Your attempts are correct, but the comparisons are evaluating `false` when compared to the 'same' object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Linq .Except* should be able to Compare equality of the Permissions objects. If you have an access to the Permissions source code then just override Equals and GetHashCode. When **defaultPermList.Except(rolePermList).ToList()** will be called - it first compare all elements on equality by *object.GetHashCode()* and thouse that has the same hashCode wolud compare with the *object.Equals()* unless we overwrite them.

```
public class Permissions
{ 

 public string Name;  // fields just for showing how to use them
 public int Rights;

 public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
    var permission = obj as Permissions;
    if (permission != null) 
       {
          if(permission?.Name.Equals(this.Name) && permission.Rights.Equals(this.Rights)
          {
             return true;
          }
       }
       return false
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
       return Name.GetHashCode() + 3*Rights.GetHashCode(); // you might use any alghorithm you see fit
    }
 }
```

That should be enough to made Except work. But if don`t have access to the Permissions source code - then you probably should write your own method and compare items there.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this by yourself if you don`t prefer the linq approach.
Basically you create an extension method for all types and go through every property and make a list of the changes (via reflections).

See here:

[Compare two objects and find the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951233/compare-two-objects-and-find-the-differences)

Here is the better version with no null pointer exception:

```
static class extentions
{ 
    public static List<Variance> DetailedCompare<T>(this T val1, T val2)
    {
        List<Variance> variances = new List<Variance>();
        FieldInfo[] fi = val1.GetType().GetFields();
        foreach (FieldInfo f in fi)
        {
            Variance v = new Variance();
            v.Prop = f.Name;
            v.valA = f.GetValue(val1);
            v.valB = f.GetValue(val2);
            if (!Equals(v.valA, v.valB))   variances.Add(v);
        }
        return variances;
    }
}
```

Variance is just a spimple class:

```
class Variance
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
    public object valA { get; set; }
    public object valB { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Variance> rt = nstanceA.DetailedCompare(InstanceB);
```